# Symfony (1.2) multiple checkbox widget

Tags: php, checkbox, symfony1, widget, checkboxlist

I want understand what the widget can I use to generate such html:

```
<input name="users[]" value="Robert" type="checkbox"> Robert
<input name="users[]" value="Bob" type="checkbox"> Bob
```

Or perhaps symfony doesn't have that widget and I have to write it myself?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check this:
[http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_2/en/A-Widgets#chapter_a_sub_choice_representations](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_2/en/A-Widgets)

As they explain, you may try this code:

```
$w = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
  'expanded' => true,
  'multiple' => true,
  'choices'  => array('A week of symfony', 'Call the expert', 'Community'),
));
```

It will produce this:
[image: multiple select with checkboxes]
<sub>(source: [symfony-project.org](http://www.symfony-project.org/images/forms_book/en/A_04.png))</sub>

Comment: Not with these parameters. With these parameters it is equivalent to sfWidgetFormSelectCheckbox . Check the link.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! I found it!
It is **sfWidgetFormSelectCheckbox** that widget I find